# Connecting MSSQL to PHP Error: [The system cannot find the file specified.]

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, sqlsrv

I am literally out of my mind now. I've been staring at the screen for god knows how many hours, and I am out of ideas. I've been trying to connect MS SQL to PHP for two weeks now; and I think I'm already crazy lol

I went to the manufacturer of the device and they don't know the solution as well, as they don't use PHP.

I have this error:
[image]

And this is my codes:

```
<?php 
/*
Connection for sqlsrv
*/
try {
    $conn = new PDO( 'sqlsrv:server=(localdb)\\v11.0;'
        . 'AttachDBFileName=C:\\PROGRAMDATA\\TOUCHLINK TIME RECORDER 3\\TA3.mdf;Database=TA3');

    $query = 'SELECT EmployeeNo, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName FROM TA3.dbo.Employees ORDER BY EmployeeNo ASC';
    $stmt = $conn->query($query);
    $stmt->execute();
} 
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

And here is my SQL Server:

[image]

And here's the path where TA3.mdf is:

C:\ProgramData\Touchlink Time Recorder 3\TA3.mdf

Comment: You want to connect the mssql database or connect the mdf file.What you want you can explain please.

Comment: connect the mdf file, i just want the data from mssql to show up on php.

Answer (score -1):

PDO initialization parameters are wrong, mssql server is a client-server database, so usually you have to specify the IP address, PORT and maybe other settings. The right way to connect must be something like this:

```
$conn = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDatabase', 'MyUsername', 'MyPassword');
```

I suggest to read more about it at 
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.connection.php (thanks @YourCommonSense)

Comment: i tried mssql:host, but i get this error:

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in C:\xampp\htdocs\sample2\sqlsrv.php:5 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\sample2\sqlsrv.php(5): PDO->__construct('mssql:host=(loc...', '', '') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\sample2\sqlsrv.php on line 5

let me check for the drivers needed.

Comment: There was an error on my previous post, please review it again, our friend @YourCommonSense just posted a helpful link about this topic.

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried the notes and examples but none of these things worked. I don't think I missed one thing in it too.